# Simple rate limiting in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

Let's say I have a login `form`:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"><input type="password" name="pwd"><input type="submit" />
```

I know that a proper rate-limiting should be done with `iptables` or `fail2ban`, but without going so far, can we do something simple, just in the `.htaccess`:

- Limit the IP for 24 hours if there has been >= 10 requests to this page during the last minute

**Can something like this be done with `.htaccess` (or `apache2.conf`) only and no other third-party tool (an Apache module is ok)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a way to 'rate limit' one particular IP and you want an Apache module for it then this might be for you: 
https://wiki.debian.org/en/Apache/mod_evasive

mod_evasive is a module that detects possible attack patterns on the network similar to an IPS (intrusion prevention system). 
A basic explanation about what an IPS does it [right here](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1722559).

To setup the module run

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive
```

Then activate the module with

```
sudo a2enmod evasive
```

Verify the installation by running

```
 sudo apachectl -M | grep evasive
```

Expected output:  *evasive20_module (shared)* 
Now we create a new folder for our apache module so it can write logs to it.

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/mod_evasive
sudo chown www-data:root /var/log/mod_evasive
```

Let's edit the config of mod_evasive. I use [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) for this example

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/evasive.conf
```

*Please note: Never edit a module configuration in /apache2/mods-enabled/ use /apache2/mods-available/ instead. The example provided above is correct.* 
This is an example configuration:

```
 <IfModule mod_evasive20.c> 
 DOSHashTableSize 3097 
 DOSPageCount 2 
 DOSSiteCount 50 
 DOSPageInterval 1 
 DOSSiteInterval 1 
 DOSBlockingPeriod 10 
 DOSEmailNotify email@yourdomain.com 
 DOSSystemCommand "echo +%s > /proc/net/xt_recent/badguys" or block them with iptables "su root -c '/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %s -j DROP'" ##command that will be sent to the system - %s = attackers ip
 DOSLogDir "/var/log/mod_evasive" 
 DOSWhitelist 127.0.0.1
 </IfModule>
```

If you want to get email notifications via sendmail use

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/mail /bin/mail
```

Finally just restart apache using

```
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

To limit the module to one location, use

```
<Directory /var/www/test/>
  <IfModule moduleLimitedToTest>
   ... do something with module
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

More on how to use containers can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html). You could place this into a site/virtualhost config. This is explained [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

*Though I'd strongly recommend the same thing as Olaf Kock.*

Comment: Thank you @devnull. What is an IPS? Could you post a sample `.htaccess` code to explain how to do such a rate limiting with `mod_evasive`?

Comment: You're welcome! You won't need any .htaccess code. mod_evasive is an apache module with it's own configuration. I just updated my answer with a detailed step-by-step instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! Is it possible to do it only for a specific directory /test/ and not the whole website ? (That's why I mentioned htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly advise against solving this problem on the level that you propose. I'd rather go for the application layer, because in the end it's most likely *failed* login attempts that you want to limit.

And as we still suffer from IPV4, and with it NAT, you won't know how many distinct legitimate browsers hide behind a single IP address.

On failure, your application can then trigger `fail2ban` or `iptables` activities. However, in times of distributed attacks and botnets I doubt that this will make much of a difference. Before you invest a lot of time, I'd recommend to inspect the logs and find out if this is a common (or rather the most common) attack path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As stated in the question, I know `fail2ban` and other such techniques are better, but just to know more about Apache possibilities, how could we do it purely at Apache level?

Comment: My first sentence says it all: "I'd strongly advise against solving this problem on the level that you propose". The rest explains this recommendation